# List View Problem

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am trying to fetch rows from the database and make a list view from it.

This is by Query method inside the DbAdapter

```
public Cursor readInbox(long toId) throws SQLException {
    return db.query(TABLE_MAILS, new String[] { ID, KEY_FROM, KEY_TO,
            KEY_SUB, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATETIME, KEY_READ }, KEY_TO + "="
            + toId, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

This is the code i am trying to write. but its giving error

```
public class InboxActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox);

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(InboxActivity.this);
        db.open();
        long userID = Long.parseLong(MessagingApplication.getUserID());

        Cursor inbox = db.readInbox(userID);
        startManagingCursor(inbox);

        String[] Id = new String[] { DBAdapter.ID };

        SimpleCursorAdapter inboxmail = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view, db, Id, null);
        setListAdapter(inboxmail);

        db.close();
    }
}
```

the Error:

```
The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(InboxActivity, int, DBAdapter, String[], null) is undefined
```

Comment: The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(InboxActivity, int, DBAdapter, String[], null) is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple compilation error.
Have a look at the public constructors at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html :

SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)

You're providing DBAdapter where you should be providing a Cursor. Most likely you should be passing the inbox variable instead of DBAdapter